# Is there a way to get the list of rsa keys created by aspnet_regiis

Tags: .net, security, iis, entity-framework-4

I have created keys on a production computer using

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "MyKeyName" –exp
```

Is there a way to export a list of all the keys names in my computer?
Thanks.

Comment: Key container for the machine account usually saved in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA.

Comment: Well, yes, for a given value if "saved" - but not with the name that I specified at aspnet_regiis.